# Apache + Passenger non-www to www => too many redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am using phusion passenger to host a rails app at www.example.com. I want to tell apache to redirect example.com to www.example.com. The standard way seems to be using two virtual host configs. I am doing this, but I am getting a "too many redirects" error. Following is my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks. I am using Passenger 3.0.11, Apache2.

Answer (score 2):

We use a single virtual host config with a .htaccess file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.mydomain.com
      ServerAlias mydomain.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/public
      <Directory /var/www/public>
         AllowOverride all
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in your /var/www/public/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```